# Add text to Tiff in Meteor

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js

Okay so I have been given the task of adding a string to the bottom of some tiff images on export to a zip file. The application used to zip is JSZipUtils.

I searched for a package that would edit the file before zipping and couldn't find anything except some packages which seemed to act as wrappers to ImageMagick, I have used ImageMagick before for resizing but boss man is worried about performance on export as the user could in theory save thousands of files at a time to a zip.

Does anyone know of a better way to add text over an image in Meteor?

Dev systems are windows and UAT & Live are Red Hat

Comment: This is a general Node/JS question, as Meteor doesn't deal with any of this

Comment: And the answer is probably going to involve imageMagick/graphicsMagic/etc